How to block DC from POE+ and allow AC to go through?
I have an RJ45 breakout board, an eth to USB-2 adapter, a POE module and an USW-Lite-8-PoE as a POE+ source
Here is a picture of all three:

I want to combine these to make a POE splitter for a Raspberry Pi Zero.
I foolishly assumed that the eth signal and power will be going over different RJ45 pins.
Signal and power is provided over the same 1,2,3,6 pins, and I'm looking for a way to block the DC power signal while allowing the AC signal through so I can connect it to the eth adapter without blowing it up.
From my research so far I conclude that wiring a capacitor in series to the above-mentioned pins will block DC and allow AC to go through.
I have the following questions I have not found an answer for:

Will the signal get distorted once it passes through the capacitor?
The switch is a gigabit capable device, ac signal will be 125 MHz
If yes, what can be done to preserve the signal integrity?
What are the values that the cap must have and what type?
Is a capacitor the only component needed?



Yes it will get distorted through a capacitor. Capacitors are not the right way to make a PoE extractor.

Make the PoE extractor correctly with a transformer, or multiple transformers, like standard PoE injectors and extractors.

None, as explained above, AC coupling with cap is not the right way

No, and neither is the capacitor.



You don't have to add any capacitor to block the DC in for POE.
I did not understood the setup which you are making exactly.
I will explain the details in general, hope it will cover the required detail.
For POE, there will be PSE (Power sourcing equipment) controller on source side and PD (powered device) controller on the load side. In your side, PSE will be USW-Lite-8-PoE and PD will be the POE module which you mentioned. To PSE will only provide if there is a PD on the other side of the link and the power output will be detected by PSE from PD.
For POE, there is no need to add any series capacitors to block the DC.
The center tap pins of ethernet magnetics will be used for Power. for example, the source is connected on the secondary side of the magnetics, the primary side center tap pins will be connected to the PD module.
And the remaining primary side pins will be connected to the link device on the other end, in your case, raspberry pi. The DC will not flow after the magnetics.
I hope you will get the required details from this.
If you can add a block diagram or any other details how you are planning your setup, I can help specific to your setup. I would like to know why you are using a USB to eth converter and a breakout board. Please provide a block diagram and explanation.
